# Dataset Cancel or Abort (the right approach)?

Tags: delphi

If I call abort only then my dataset is still in dsedit state.
I have to hit ESC twice or hit the cancel button (dbnavigator) to exit.

I cant call cancel because my table is not in edit mode (error) .

This way :

```
procedure TDataModule.MYTABLEBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
with VALIDATE_ENTRY do begin
VALIDATE_ENTRY.Close;
VALIDATE_ENTRY.SQL.Clear;
VALIDATE_ENTRY.SQL.Text := 'SELECT [NAME] FROM UNITS WHERE [NAME] = '+ QuotedStr(UNITS.FieldByName('NAME').asString) ; 
VALIDATE_ENTRY.Open;
if EOF then begin
MYTABLE.Post;
end else
ShowMessage('NAME '+UNITS.FieldByName('NAME').asString+' already exists !'+#13#10+'Entry is forbidden !');
Dataset.Cancel;
Abort;
end;
end;
```

seems to work but it sure feels weird.

Is this OK to use or is there another elegant way to achieve this ?

Comment: It's ok to call abort to interrupt the event, but you should not call post inside the before post event. I am almost sure that your question is dup. I'm trying to find the other one

Comment: Fwiw, it's asking for trouble doing things like calling MYTABLE.Post inside its own BeforePost event.

Comment: You can also check if the name exist in the event onvalidate of a TField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with previous answer. Cancel will cause the data already entered to be lost. Imagine that your user has typed DOZENS of fields and just because he/she typed something wrong, he/she will be obligated to type it all again? This is not how software should work.
If the software user did something wrong, preserve his work and give him a chance to correct and post again. This is what an exception does in place of DataSet.Cancel.

Also, your pattern:

```
ShowMessage('NAME '+UNITS.FieldByName('NAME').asString+' already exists !'+#13#10+'Entry is forbidden !');
Abort;
```

is wrong IMO. You should use:

```
raise Exception.Create('your error message here');
```

or even better, create your own Exception descendant and raise it instead, something like:

```
raise EYourDBExceptionClass.Create('your error message here');
```

Comment: The OP stated (or implied) that they wanted to return to dsBrowse mode (i.e. The same as pressing the Cancel button) which of course loses any pending edits.

Comment: Yes, but I still think that he should consider other - better - approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Just call `Dataset.Cancel` . That will put you back in Browse mode. Calling Abort will leave you in a `dsEdit` state.  To allow the edit don't call anything.

Comment: This is the best solution.